# How to loop a VBA code to run every column value (20,000+ cells) without it being slow

Tags: excel, vba, loops, range

I made a VBA code that has a if then statement that says if a specific cell value in workbook 1 equals to a specific cell value in workbook 2, and if another cell in the same row in workbook 2 equals to a certain value, then return the words `True` in workbook 1 specific range , else return `False`.

For example, if the name Apple from Workbook 1 Column `A2` exists within Workbook 2 Column Range B and if in Workbook 2, column C which is `"Type" = Fruit`, then return True in Workbook 1 cell `H2:I2`, else return `False`.

What I am struggling with is getting that to loop for each cell, as I tried with my current code and my macro would freeze and say "not responding".  In workbook 1, there are 20,000+ possible cells, and in workbook2 there are 40,000+ possible cells so I'm wondering if that is the reason.

Also in line `Sheet1.Range("H2:I2").Value = "True"` , I want `("H2:I2")` to always change so that if for example I am referencing cell E3, that range would have to change to `H3:I3`, `E4` would be `H4:I4` and so on.

Any suggestions? Thanks

**Here is my code:**

```vb
Sub Worksheet_Change()

Dim KeyCells As Range
Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet
Dim Sheet2 As Worksheet
Dim CellChanged As Integer
Dim Path, File As String
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastRow1 As Long
Dim i As Long

Set Sheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data") 'Edit Sheet File1
Set KeyCells = Range("E:E")
Set Sheet2 = Workbooks("Data.xlsx").Worksheets("MyData") 'Edit Sheet of File2

LastRow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Lastrow2 = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To LastRow
    For j = 1 To LastRow

        If Sheet1.Range("E2" & j).Value = Sheet2.Range("C" & i).Value And Sheet2.Range("F" & i).Value = "LAX" Then
            Sheet1.Range("H2:I2").Value = "True"
        Else: Sheet1.Range("H2:I2").Value = "False"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

**EDIT
Thanks for the suggestion about making an array but I've never made one before. How would I paste my array back into my first workbook 1 after doing a loop within it? For reference, my workbook 1 has 12 columns and 20,000+ rows.

Comment: Add `Application.Screenupdating = false` before the loop and `Application.Screenupdating = true` after it

Comment: Also, work with arrays, then drop the data back to your sheet. Will increase the speed a lot.

Comment: To speed this up instead of writing your output for every hit, you could read all this into an array, and then writing this array in one go. Especially with large numbers of operations, this really cuts down on heavy write actions.

Comment: Also don't declare variables, which You are not using, exmple: `KeyCells`

Comment: if `j = 10` then `("E2" & j)` => E210. is it must be so?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your suggestions on the array. Please refer to my question under edit.

Answer (score 0):

VBA doesn't use [short circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). Therefore you need to construct your `If` statements with that in mind. It's worth splitting up conditions, if the "outer" condition would evaluate to *False* more often than not and therefore skip to the next loop iteration, not executing the next comparison. E.g. assuming that most of the values of the F column in Sheet2 are **not** *"LAX"*, it might be worth to try the following:

```
If Sheet2.Range("F" & i).Value = "LAX" Then
    If Sheet1.Range("E2" & j).Value = Sheet2.Range("C" & i).Value Then
        Sheet1.Range("H2:I2").Value = "True"
        ' [...]
```